# SharePoint page with usercontrol is giving You are not authorized to view this page error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, smartpart

I have an unusual scenario in which only one page of our SP 2007 site is throwing this error "You are not authorized to view this page".

Here are some details:
SP 2007 Enterprise
The page in question uses SmartPart to display custom usercontrol.
We have 50+ pages that also use custom user controls in SmartPart, and none of them generate this error.

The page in question has several functions, and it initially loads just fine.  First time it loads, user selects a customer from a dropdown, then enters a search query and clicks the search button.  That all works, and the page then returns some search results.  That works as well.  The the user can click on a Modify link for each item.  It's clicking on this Modify link that generates the page error.  All of these things are done one this one page, it just refreshes accordingly.  The Modify link is just a standard asp:commandline field that causes the page to load the line item in editable mode.

Here's the other strange thing.  If I login as the SP Administrator account, and go to this page, it all works properly, no errors...and, then all other users can go in and use the page properly, without errors as well.  It's as if whatever the security issue is, is being resolved temporarily as a result of the Admin using the page first. But after a code publish, or IISRESET, etc, the page goes back to not working for any general users.

Any ideas on what I should look for in trying to resolve this issue?  I can also provide code if anyone thinks that may be relevant.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably has some issues with zones and alternate access mappings, and my guess is you're using localhost/plain hostname in your URLs in one place, and FQDNs in the other. Please show the URL to the page in question, as well as the URLs you get when you hover over the links.

Answer (score 2):

```
use SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges for running your code with anonymous access user:
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(web.Site.ID))
        {
        // implementation details omitted
        }
    });
```